# Using chrome = Application(backend='uia') how do I get to the login field?

Tags: python, windows, pywinauto

I want to get to the login field at the home depot website [home depot website](https://citiretailservices.citibankonline.com/RSnextgen/svc/launch/index.action?siteId=PLCN_HOMEDEPOT#signon&cmp=A%7EC%7EC%7EM%7EZ%7EZ%7EZZZZ%7EZZ%7EHD%7EZZ&desc=R%7EA%7EI%7EZ%7EZ%7EZ%7EZZZZ%7EZZ%7EHD)])
using the uia commands as it won't accept selenium.
My code to access site
`

```
chrome = Application(backend='uia')
chrome.start(chrome_dir + ' --force-renderer-accessibility '
             'https://online.citi.com/US/ag/accountdetails?accountId=8f551182-ecec-4c86-8f75-dabb124e16f6')
```

`

I can't find how to access the login field.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using tabs...
{

```
# # start google chrome
chrome = Application(backend='uia')
chrome.start(chrome_dir + ' --disable-logging --force-renderer-accessibility -remote-debugging-port=8080 '
             'https://citiretailservices.citibankonline.com/RSnextgen/svc/launch/index.action?siteId=PLCN_HOMEDEPOT#signon&cmp=A~C~C~M~Z~Z~ZZZZ~ZZ~HD~ZZ&desc=R~A~I~Z~Z~Z~ZZZZ~ZZ~HD')
sleep(4)
chrome.window().type_keys('{F5}')  # tab key
sleep(10)
chrome.window().type_keys('{TAB}')  # tab key
chrome.window().type_keys('{TAB}')  # tab key
chrome.window().type_keys('{TAB}')  # tab key
chrome.window().type_keys('{TAB}')  # tab key
chrome.window().type_keys('{TAB}')  # tab key
chrome.window().type_keys('{TAB}')  # tab key
chrome.window().type_keys('{TAB}')  # tab key
chrome.window().type_keys('{TAB}')  # tab key
chrome.window().type_keys('{TAB}')  # tab key
sleep(2)
chrome.window().type_keys('MyUserID')  # username
chrome.window().type_keys('{TAB}')  # tab key
chrome.window().type_keys('{TAB}')  # tab key
sleep(.5)
chrome.window().type_keys('Mypass {ENTER}')  # password
sleep(8)
```

}